# How to work with null pointers in a std::vector

Tags: c++, stdvector

Say I have a vector of null terminates strings some of which may be null pointers. I don't know even if this is legal. It is a learning exercise.
 Example code

```
std::vector<char*> c_strings1;
char* p1 = "Stack Over Flow";
c_strings1.push_back(p1);
p1 = NULL; // I am puzzled you can do this and what exactly is stored at this memory location
c_strings1.push_back(p1);
p1 = "Answer";
c_strings1.push_back(p1);
for(std::vector<char*>::size_type i = 0; i < c_strings1.size(); ++i)
{
  if( c_strings1[i] != 0 )
  {
    cout << c_strings1[i] << endl;
  }
}
```

Note that the size of vector is 3 even though I have a NULL at location `c_strings1[1]`
**Question**. How can you re-write this code using `std::vector<char>`
 What exactly is stored in the vector when you push a null value? 

**EDIT**
The first part of my question has been thoroughly answered but not the second. Not to my statisfaction at least. I **do** want to see usage of `vector<char>`; not some nested variant or `std::vector<std::string>` Those are familiar. So here is what I tried ( hint: it does not work)

```
std::vector<char> c_strings2;
string s = "Stack Over Flow";
c_strings2.insert(c_strings2.end(), s.begin(), s.end() );
//  char* p = NULL; 
s = ""; // this is not really NULL, But would want a NULL here
c_strings2.insert(c_strings2.end(), s.begin(), s.end() );
s = "Answer";
c_strings2.insert(c_strings2.end(), s.begin(), s.end() );

const char *cs = &c_strings2[0];
while (cs <= &c_strings2[2]) 
{
  std::cout << cs << "\n";
  cs += std::strlen(cs) + 1;
}
```

Comment: Just don't use C-strings in C++. If you used `std::string` I think these questions would just go away.

Comment: You're a bit confused because of "null terminated strings, some of which may be null pointers". A null-terminated string is an array of characters, the last one of which is 0. The null pointer doesn't point to anything. Therefore the null pointer doesn't point to a null-terminated string either. So your vector contains a mix of null-terminated strings and null pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a funny feeling that what you would really want is to have the vector contain something like `"Stack Over Flow Answer"` (possibly without space before `"Answer"`).

In this case, you can use a `std::vector<char>`, you just have to push the whole arrays, not just pointers to them.

This cannot be accomplished with `push_back`, however `vector` have an `insert` method that accept ranges.

```
/// Maintain the invariant that the vector shall be null terminated
/// p shall be either null or point to a null terminated string
void push_back(std::vector<char>& v, char const* p) {
  if (p) {
    v.insert(v.end(), p, p + strlen(p));
  }

  v.push_back('\0');
} // push_back

int main() {
  std::vector<char> v;

  push_back(v, "Stack Over Flow");
  push_back(v, 0);
  push_back(v, "Answer");

  for (size_t i = 0, max = v.size(); i < max; i += strlen(&v[i]) + 1) {
    std::cout << &v[i] << "\n";
  }
}
```

This uses a single contiguous buffer to store multiple null-terminated strings. Passing a null string to `push_back` results in an empty string being displayed.

Comment: Ah! I like your approach. Now how do you iterate over v to print all the individual strings not just the first one. Of course you have to skip over the null value

Comment: @user841550: wait, do you want the individual strings or do you want a single string ? I must admit I am confused with your requirements...

Comment: I want individual strings. Pls see EDIT part of my question where I attempt to store the strings and iterate the vector. It is how to handle the null element that I can't handle

Comment: @user841550: I've updated the answer to display the multiple strings and keep them separated (using the null character as a marker).

Comment: This is the best answer so far to the second part of my question. For completeness if you can provide an answer the first ( it has been aswered by several already or just point to the best answer e.g. @sharth) I will accept your answer because this was the more important part of my question

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to upvote. I will come back when I do. I think @Dibling has similar solution but has answered both questions

Comment: @user841550: Don't worry about the reputation, I have more than enough and I'm just glad I could help :) Do not hesitate to accept John's response rather than mine if it's more complete/helpful to you.

Comment: I am still trying to uderstand your `for` loop. It produces the result that I expect but I don't quite uderstand what it is doing. In particular I would like to inside the loop identify which index has a NULL and return a bool ( F ) or bool (T) and a string if it is not null

Answer (score 5):

You don't have a `vector` of strings -- you have a `vector` of pointer-to-char.  NULL is a perfectly valid pointer-to-char which happens to not point to anything, so it is stored in the vector.

Note that the pointers you are actually storing are pointers to char literals.  The strings are not copied.

It doesn't make a lot of sense to mix the C++ style `vector` with the C-style char pointers.  Its not illegal to do so, but mixing paradigms like this often results in confused & busted code.

Instead of using a `vector<char*>` or a `vector<char>`, why not use a `vector<string>` ?

### EDIT

Based on your edit, it seems like what your'e trying to do is flatten several strings in to a single `vector<char>`, with a NULL-terminator between each of the flattened strings.

Here's a simple way to accomplish this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // create a vector of strings...
    typedef vector<string> Strings;
    Strings c_strings;

    c_strings.push_back("Stack Over Flow");
    c_strings.push_back("");
    c_strings.push_back("Answer");

    /* Flatten the strings in to a vector of char, with 
        a NULL terminator between each string

        So the vector will end up looking like this:

        S t a c k _ O v e r _ F l o w \0 \0 A n s w e r \0

    ***********************************************************/

    vector<char> chars;
    for( Strings::const_iterator s = c_strings.begin(); s != c_strings.end(); ++s )
    {
        // append this string to the vector<char>
        copy( s->begin(), s->end(), back_inserter(chars) );
        // append a null-terminator
        chars.push_back('\0');
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure string literals have global lifetime (+1 for good answer).

Comment: @John Dibling I want to use vector<char> because it allows me to pass contiguous memory to C fucntions in non-const fashion

Comment: @User, then you will need `vector< vector< char > >`, not `vector< char >`

Comment: @John Dibling But a nested vector does not have contiguous memory. I am goint to edit my question and add my attempt of what I tried to do

Answer (score 2):

So,

```
char *p1 = "Stack Over Flow";
char *p2 = NULL;
char *p3 = "Answer";
```

If you notice, the type of all three of those is exactly the same. They are all `char *`. Because of this, we would expect them all to have the same size in memory as well.

You may think that it doesn't make sense for them to have the same size in memory, because p3 is shorter than p1. What actually happens, is that the compiler, at compile-time, will find all of the strings in the program. In this case, it would find `"Stack Over Flow"` and `"Answer"`. It will throw those to some constant place in memory, that it knows about. Then, when you attempt to say that `p3 = "Answer"`, the compiler actually transforms that to something like `p3 = 0x123456A0`.

Therefore, with either version of the push_back call, you are only pushing into the vector a pointer, not the actual string itself.

The vector itself, doesn't know, or care that a `NULL char *` is an empty string. So in it's counting, it sees that you have pushed three pointers into it, so it reports a size of 3.

Comment: Don't assign string literals to `char*`. Use `char[]` or `const char*`.

Comment: I don;t see the relevance of all that about the compiler "finding all the strings in a program."

Comment: @JohnDibling: The only relevance is to show how a system will store that information (The strings) without changing the size of the object  you are storing them in. It somewhat relates to the bolded question at the end of the question.

Comment: Its still not relevant though, because even if the compiler didn't do any of this, the sizes of all the items being stored in the `vector` would still be the same.

Comment: @sharth You have the best explanation for the first part of my question. I still want to understand how the three elements in the first vector can be stored ( if at all possible ) in the second vector `vector<char>`

Comment: @user841550: You can't push a null explicitly. There's also no simple way to encode the difference between the null string, and a null character in the method you're requesting.

Answer (score 0):

> What exactly is stored in the vector when you push a null value?

A `NULL`. You're storing pointers, and `NULL` is a possible value for a pointer. Why is this unexpected in any way?

Also, use `std::string` as the value type (i.e. `std::vector<std::string>`), `char*` shouldn't be used unless it's needed for C interop. To replicate your code using `std::vector<char>`, you'd need `std::vector<std::vector<char>>`.

Comment: Lets assume C interop is absolutely essential in this case. A nested vector will not do it. A std::sting cannot be modifies by C fucntions

Comment: @user841550: The best way to figure out how to do interop depends on what you're interacting with. I don't think I've ever needed a vector of `char*`.

Answer (score 0):

NULL is just 0. A pointer with value 0 has a meaning. But a char with value 0 has [a different meaning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character). It is used as a delimiter to show the end of a string. Therefore, if you use `std::vector<char>` and `push_back` 0, the vector will contain a character with value 0. `vector<char>` is a vector of characters, while `std::vector<char*>` is a vector of C-style strings -- very different things.

**Update.** As the OP wants, I am giving an idea of how to store (in a vector) null terminated strings some of which are nulls.

**Option 1**: Suppose we have `vector<char> c_strings;`. Then, we define a function to store a string pi. A lot of complexity is introduced since we need to distinguish between an empty string and a null char*. We select a delimiting character that does not occur in our usage. Suppose this is the '~' character.

```
char delimiter = '~';
// push each character in pi into c_strings
void push_into_vec(vector<char>& c_strings, char* pi) {
  if(pi != 0) {
    for(char* p=pi; *p!='\0'; p++) 
      c_strings.push_back(*p);
    // also add a NUL character to denote end-of-string
    c_strings.push_back('\0');
  }
  c_strings.push_back(deimiter);
  // Note that a NULL pointer would be stored as a single '~' character
  // while an empty string would be stored as '\0~'.
}
 
// now a method to retrieve each of the stored strings. 
vector<char*> get_stored_strings(const vector<char>& c_strings) {
  vector<char*> r;
  char* end = &c_strings[0] + c_strings.size();
  char* current = 0;
  bool nullstring = true; 
  for(char* c = current = &c_strings[0]; c != end+1; c++) {
    if(*c == '\0') {
      int size = c - current - 1;
      char* nc = new char[size+1];
      strncpy(nc, current, size);  
      r.push_back(nc);     
      nullstring = false; 
    }
    if(*c == delimiter) {
      if(nullstring) r.push_back(0);     
      nullstring = true; // reset nullstring for the next string
      current = c+1; // set the next string
    }
  }
  return r;
}
```

You still need to call `delete[]` on the memory allocated by `new[]` above. All this complexity is taken care of by using the `string` class. I very rarely use `char*` in C++.

**Option 2:** You could use `vector<boost::optional<char> >` . Then the '~' can be replaced by an empty boost::optional, but other other parts are the same as option 1. But the memory usage in this case would be higher.

Comment: So it is impossible to store the three elements in vector<char>?

Comment: It is possible, but not in a way that senior programmers would like, unless in unusual circumstances.

Comment: For example, to store the three strings, you could devise a scheme that two strings would be separated by a single NUL character. But this makes manipulation of stored strings inefficient and the scheme non-simple.

Comment: I am interested to see how this can be done. i.e. how you can store null terminate strings some of which may be nulls in a vector. As I said this is for learning

Comment: Wow! That is quite involved, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful when storing pointers in STL containers - copying the containers results in shallow copy and things like that.

With regard to your specific question, the vector will store a pointer of type char* regardless of whether or not that pointer points to something.  It's entirely possible you would want to store a null-pointer of type char* within that vector for some reason - for example, what if you decide to delete that character string at a later point from the vector?  Vectors only support amortized constant time for push_back and pop_back, so there's a good chance if you were deleting a string inside that vector (but not at the end) that you would prefer to just set it null quickly and save some time.

Moving on - I would suggest making a std::vector > if you want a dynamic array of strings which looks like what you're going for.

A std::vector as you mentioned would be useless compared to your original code because your original code stores a dynamic array of strings and a std::vector would only hold one dynamically changable string (as a string is an array of characters essentially).